# python: if-else in value definition as argument

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

**NOTE**: it is NOT Symbol to Digit converter!!! i am using that structure as example only!!

i have to use following structure to define new column in dataframe. Is there better and more accurate structure to archive the same result, something like "case"?

```
df['type']  = ['1' if x  == 'A' else 
              ('2' if x  == 'B' else 
              ('3' if x  == 'C' else 
              ('9' if x  == 'D' else 0))) for x in df['argument']]
```

Comment: `[{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '9'}.get(x, 0) for x in ...]`

Answer (score 0):

`.apply` is your friend.

```py
def argument_fxn(x):
    if x=='A':
        return '1'
    elif x=='B':
        return '2'
    elif x=='C':
        return '3'
    elif x=='D':
        return '9'
    else:
        return 0

df['type'] = df['argument'].apply(argument_fxn)
```

Comment: What is `.apply`? Can you include the link to the definition?

Comment: thanks, but it is the same structure.